# Как сделать такую раскладку используя Bootstrap или float? (скрины и заготовки в песочнице внутри)

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Цель - вот такая раскладка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока получается реализовать только вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[Заготовка jsbin c float](https://jsbin.com/texoserema/edit?html,css,output)
[Заготовка jsbin c Bootstrap](https://jsbin.com/maqekoloku/edit?html,css,output)

Можно передвинуть блок 3 вверх - через postion: relative.
Но появиться ненужное пустое пространство внизу.

Сделать обертки-колонки для блоков 1,3 и 2,4 нет возможности.

**Какие можно поднять блок 3 и не добавлять пустое пространство внизу?**
(песочницы с кодом для эксперементов - см. выше)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С **float** всё просто : достаточно вашему блоку поставить отрицательный **margin-top**

```css
.block1 {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  color: black;
}

.block3 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.block4 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="block1">1</div>

  <div class="block2">2</div>

  <div class="block3">3</div>

  <div class="block4">4</div>

  <div class="block1">1</div>

  <div class="block2">2</div>

  <div class="block3">3</div>

  <div class="block4">4</div>

</body>

</html>
```

А вот bootsrap не занимаюсь но скажу что для этих целей идеально подходит **grid**

Comment: Спасибо! C grid согласен, но тут IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Если колонок только две, то достаточно второму блоку дать `float: right;`.

Соответственно, в третьем Бутстрапе для этого предусмотрен [класс `pull-right`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-floats):

```css
.block1{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 200px;
}
.block2{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 300px;
}
.block3{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
}
.block4{
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="block1">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
      <div class="block2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="block3">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="block4">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```